# how to test private React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I recently took a job that isnt using ES6 yet in there react project. I have a ES6 background and just wrote a large file that I cant figure out how to test without using ES6.

Basically, I have a main component, that has about 7 or so private components that are mostly built as separate components for readability, testing and performance. (Being able to have a should component update on private components is a huge boost)

Here is my issue:

without exporting my private components I cant find a way to write tests them.

because we are not using ES6, I cant use the

```
export default MyComponent
export PrivateComponent1
export PrivateComponent2
```

syntax, the only way I know of to export multiple components from a single file is to use

```
exports.MyComponent = MyComponent
exports.PrivateComponent1 = PrivateComponent1
exports.PrivateComponent2 = PrivateComponent2
```

however this is not good because then in the require statement I need to use

```
const MyComponent = require('MyComponent').MyComponent
```

Ideally I would like to use something like:

```
module.exports = MyComponent
exports.PrivateComponent1 = PrivateComponent1
exports.PrivateComponent2 = PrivateComponent2
```

But that doesnt seem to be valid.

Additionally, it is preferred not to break this up into separate files.

...This is what i get for not doing TDD :(

Comment: Why do you have multiple components in one file? Ideally you would abstract each component into its own file even if its being used by only one other component. The layer of abstraction has its own benefits plus you can just export each component individually and not deal with the multiple exports one file problem

Comment: the components can get very granular, which I believe really helps readability, performance and debugging. They didnt want to pollute the folder with a bunch of smaller components.

Comment: In that case I would say your only option is exporting an object with key/value pairs and having to do `const MyComponent = require('MyComponent').MyComponent`

Comment: Hmm... I was afraid of that, and thats not an option for them either. There solution was to not break it up into private components and instead put all the jsx in the parents render function. Im a little bummed out that my readability is not as nice now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## CommonJS Modules

```
module.exports = MyComponent
exports.PrivateComponent1 = PrivateComponent1
exports.PrivateComponent2 = PrivateComponent2
```

That's not possible because `exports` is an alias to `module.exports` and after setting `module.exports` the properties in `exports` won't be exported.

What transpilers ([Babel](https://babeljs.io/)) do is to create a "default" property.

## ES2015

So, the following code in ES2015:

```
import AnotherModule from './anotherModule';

export default class Foo {}

export class Bar {}
```

will be transpiled to:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.Bar = undefined;

var _anotherModule = require('./anotherModule');

var _anotherModule2 = _interopRequireDefault(_anotherModule);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Foo = function Foo() {
  _classCallCheck(this, Foo);
};

exports.default = Foo;

var Bar = exports.Bar = function Bar() {
  _classCallCheck(this, Bar);
};
```

Notice the line `exports.default = Foo;` and `var Bar = exports.Bar = ...`.

In order to import that module in another file without using ES2015 (and neither a transpiler) you use `var Foo = require('./myPreviousModule').default`.

Babel creates an interop function (see the function `_interopRequireDefault`) to allow users to import Node CommonJS modules and ES2015 ones in the same way.

Comment: This is a great answer, so the short answer is that there isnt magic that can do what I exactly want. (they will complain about using .default to) But this some great information to show me why i cant do what i want. Thanks!